# Centering a view with auto constraints - Swift

Tags: swift, constraints

I am creating an XIB/class of datePicker which is called programatically from a calling viewController when the user taps a button.  How can I use auto constraints to place this view immediately below and aligned with the centre of the calling button.  My code works in portrait, but fails when the device is rotated (the datePicker does not re-center).  Probably because I am passing a CGRect as an argument on init of the view, which doesn't change on rotate. I can't see any other way of overriding the passing of CGRect. When I add in auto constraints code, I get run-time auto formatting errors.

ViewController:

```
@IBAction func showMyDatePicker(_ sender: Any) {
    showMyDatePicker.isEnabled = false
    let today = Date()
    let minDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -3, to: today)
    let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 3, to: today)

    let datePickerWidth = 300
    let datePickerHeight = 200

    let datePickerX = Int(showMyDatePicker.center.x - CGFloat(datePickerWidth / 2))
    let datePickerY = Int(showMyDatePicker.center.y + CGFloat(showMyDatePicker.bounds.height / 2))
    let frame = CGRect(x: datePickerX, y: datePickerY, width: datePickerWidth, height: datePickerHeight)

    myDatePicker = MyDatePicker(frame: frame)
    myDatePicker?.setMyDatePicker(date: today, minimumDate: minDate!, maximumDate: maxDate!)
    myDatePicker?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(myDatePicker!)

}
```

datePickerClass:

```
class MyDatePicker: UIView {

var delegate: MyDatePickerDelegate?

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var returnButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.dateFromDatePicker(date: datePicker.date, closeDatePickerView: false)
}

@IBAction func returnButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.dateFromDatePicker(date: datePicker.date, closeDatePickerView: true)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    initView()
}

private func initView() {//QUESTION: how can I set the datepicker initial values within here
    // Instantiate the view from xib file
    let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyDatePicker", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView

    // Check that it's not nil
    guard contentView != nil else {
        return
    }

    // Add the view and set its frame
    addSubview(contentView!)
    contentView?.frame = self.bounds
    contentView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}


func setMyDatePicker(date: Date, minimumDate: Date, maximumDate: Date) {
    datePicker.date = date
    datePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate
    datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate
}
```

}

Comment: what error you get ? can you share screen shot ? and what you tried for adding constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the required constraint after `addSubview` and setting `TAMIC` to false as follows:

```
@IBAction func showMyDatePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // ...
    view.addSubview(myDatePicker!)
    myDatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myDatePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.bottomAnchor),
        myDatePicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.centerXAnchor)])
}
```